# auto update data from AJAX posting form

Tags: php, ajax

I am using an AJAX script to post data from a form and return the processed data from a php file. The script is below.

```
    function loadXmlDoc(hashtag){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            document.getElementById("ajaxify").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "demo_ajax3.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("hashtag=" + hashtag);
    }
```

However I want to auto update the results. how would I get this to auto update so it checks for more data? Or what would be the best way?

There seems to be nothing about getting AJAX forms to auto refresh from what I've seen so any help would be greatly apprecaited

Comment: There is a lot of information regarding XHR. I am not quite sure what your are trying to achieve. What kind of 'extra info' would you require? Basically, you need to tell the server everything that it is missing and get back a response you can work with. 
BTW, I would suggest the use of a JS framework, such as JQuery, to streamline the process and reduce the amount of code needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way. It should auto-update the result every 10 seconds.

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else{
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
    document.getElementById("ajaxify").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
function loadXmlDoc(hashtag){
  var repeat = function () {
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "demo_ajax3.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("hashtag=" + hashtag);
  };
  repeat.hashtag = hashtag;
  setInterval(function() { repeat(); },10000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. That is pretty much what I wanted to achieve which was auto refresh my search so it stores tweets automatically